# Given an Assertion ID, what information Shibboleth can provide to me?

Tags: logging, saml-2.0, assertion, shibboleth

I have a question about Shibboleth: 
Given an Assertion ID, what information Shibboleth can provide to me? I need to create a web service to provide some information about the users activities for some security purposes. I need to have (based an Assertion ID as an input) at least the login time, the logout time, the user or userId, and so on. 
How can I get this information of Shibboleth logs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear from where you intend to do this. Are you talking about interrogating an IdP or a Service Provider log? Will your web service be hosted in the same environment as the Shibboleth service?

Comment: Hi Mentatmatt. Thanks for your response. We want to provide some information based on an Assertion Id for some auditing purposes. We have the IdP and have no control over the SP. We can host our service on the same machine as the IdP resides. Thanks.